# correct settings for cgminer 4.9.2

Tags: cgminer, antminer, u3

I have recently switched my mining from 4.6.1 to 4.9.2 with the same Antminer U3. Still wondering about correct settings for this new one. On 4.6.1 I have used --bsmc-options and other settings as --bsmc. On 4.9.2 syntax is different from it - it's --au3. But 4.9.2 do not understand commans --au3-options: 115200-0,65 and some others where bsmc became au3. WHat I do wrong? My stats drops down to the half of it was on 4.6.1, show very little number HW errors and stales/dups. Could someone give me the tips of correct .bat and .conf for 4.9.2/U3 os XP?

Answer (score 1):

bmsc only works with the BITMAIN cgminer...

I have fully tested and configured cgminer 4.9.2, the latest to work with the U3, check out my videos on vimeo and dailymotion, do a search for cgminer and antminer u3, full instructions are included.

I have bfgminer working with the U3 as well....